# How to add Objects to Class with a loop in Python?

Tags: python, maya

I have a class which looks like this.

```
class CharInStageList(object):
    def __init__(self, charid, charname) :
        self.charid = charid
        self.charname = charname
```

into this class I would like to add lists that I have.

I know how to do it the normal way

```
charOne = CharInStageList(1,'Tim')
charTwo = CharInStageList(2,'Struppi')
```

that's not a problem what I actually want to do is to add them by using a loop.

I get my data in this form

```
((1,'Tim'),(4,'Struppi'))
```

or

```
((1,'Tim'),(4,'Struppi'),(5,'Nami'),(6,'Luffy'))
```

the amount of characters I have in the scene is always different.
what I imagined would be a loop like this

```
charlist = ((1,'Tim'),(4,'Struppi'))
for char in charlist
    objname = CharInStageList(char[0],char[1])
```

something like this

I want the objname to change by itself for every object I add to the class.

How can I get this effect?
I can only use python 2.6.6 for this since it's the maya 2013 python

Edit:

Thx @silas-ray @chepner @theodox I looked into Dicts a bit more and that's pretty much what I need
I use a modified version of @chepner method on it.

```
object_dict = dict( (y, CharInStageList(x,y)) for x,y in data )
```

Works like a charm

My testcode looks like this

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
dicttest = {}

def getdata ():  
    global dicttest   
    data = ((1,'Tim'),(4,'Struppi'),(5,'Nami'),(6,'Luffy'))
    dicttest = dict( (y,(x,y)) for x,y in data )

getdata()

def printtest() :
    for char in dicttest:
        print dicttest[char]

printtest()
dicttest.clear()
```

I would have liked to comment in your answers with code examples but I can't get that to work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are not added to a class. Instead, you can create a list of objects which are all instances of the same class, using a list comprehension and taking advantage of the `*args` syntax:

```
data = ((1,'Tim'),(4,'Struppi'),(5,'Nami'),(6,'Luffy'))
object_list = [ CharInStageList(*x) for x in data ]
```

Perhaps you want a dictionary instead:

```
object_dict = dict( (y, CharInStageList(x,y)) for x,y in data )
```

(Note that `CharInStageList` is a poor name for the class, because it's not a list; it encapsulates a single character.)

If you really want `CharInStateList` to be a collection of characters, try something like this, which is just a thin wrapper around a dictionary:

```
# Your former CharInStageList
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, charid, charname) :
        self.charid = charid
        self.charname = char name

class OnStageCharacters(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.characters = dict()

    # Index on-stage characters using their charid
    def add(self, character):
        self.characters[character.charid] = character

on_stage = OnStageCharacters()
for id, name in data:
    on_stage.add( Character(id, name) )
```

Comment: This is a bit embarrassing but i try to comment with some code like 30 times now and i'm pretty sure i did the spaceing right since it works with the question. but it won't come over correctly.

Comment: Code is tricky in comments. You can edit your question to clarify what you want. I'm guessing, though, that you want `CharInStateList` to act as a container. I'll try updating my answer with what I think you might be trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (at least not without hacking at `locals`/`globals`, which is generally not a good idea) change the name you are assigning to dynamically like that.  You can, however, insert them in to a dictionary where the keys are your dynamically generated names.

```
characters = {}
for char_data in char_list:
    characters[char_data[1]] = CharInStageList(*char_data)
```

Though if all your character objects are storing is name and id, it might make more sense to simplify the whole thing and just create mapping dictionaries rather than objects.

```
character_names_by_id = dict(char_data)
character_ids_by_name = dict((name, id) for id, name in char_data)
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python. Are dicts Global?
The only reason i tryed using classes is because they are global and keep the correct Value.

I will experiment with dicts a bit to see if they can do what i need.

thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Neither dicts nor classes (nor class instances for that matter) are inherently global.  If you need to maintain a reference to the instance once you leave the scope in which they were created, you should package them in an object or a module and then pass that object around.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner's answer is a great one if you can use the *args form to fill out your class instances.

If you're just asking the most efficient way to do this from a loop, remember you can have iterate over the parts of a tuple together:

```
data = ((1,'Tim'),(4,'Struppi'),(5,'Nami'),(6,'Luffy'))
class_data = (CharInStageList(id, name) for id, name in data)  # "for id, name" will yield two vals
```

You can also use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), which is very common for doing bulk data translations. A common way to do it is with a lambda so you can write it clearly:

```
to_char = lambda k: CharInStageList(k[0], k[1])
class_data = map(to_char, data)
```

If you're doing something as simple as your example, you might not want to bother with your own class. the [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) is a great data structure for creating tuples that are easy to work with.  It also means you can use positional or named args interchangeably, just as in @chepner's *args version:

```
StageListChar  = namedtuple('CharInStageList', ['id', 'name'])
class_data = map(StageListChar , data)
```

Comment: this is starting to be a lot now XD. starting to get a bit dizzy. what i need is just a way to transfer a list of charachters like that which is generated by one def to another def to be used further. and the list looks like that.
but thanks for all the great ways to do it :) i will look into it. trying to learn as much as possible for future projects.